# how to automate running a python script

Tags: python, automation, cron

How can I automate running of 3 python scripts. Suppose, I have 3 scripts say a.py,b.py and c.py.

Here a.py runs a web crawler and saves it as a xml file. Now b.py parses the xml file generated and saves as a pickle file. Now c.py inserts the list from pickle file to database.

Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: What operating system are you on? Also, what do you mean by automate? Do you want them to run on a fixed schedule or in response to certain events?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 11.10, by automate i mean to say that I want these 3 scripts to run every 2-3 hours.

Answer (score 7):

Just make a shell script which does

`python a.py && python b.py && python c.py`

The `&&` in bash is for chaining commands consecutively, e.g. here `b.py` would only execute if `a.py` completed successfully (i.e. returned 0).

Save it in a file with no extension (some version of cron won't use `.sh` files, I found this out the long and frustrating way), then put the location of that shell script in your cron table using `crontab -e`.  There is plenty of information on [superuser](https://superuser.com/) about how to schedule cron jobs, so I recommend to search there for this information rather than here on SO (which is more about programming).

Comment: `*/2 * * * *  /home/ching/Desktop/scrapper/scrap` im using this to run my scripts in crontab every 2 minutes. But i dont see any xml file generated. Is something wrong in this?

Comment: have you `chmod +x` on the script?  you can use `run-parts --test` to check what cron will run

Answer (score 0):

Write a wrapper python script that imports a, b and c and runs then in sequence (with error checking, notification and accounting). Then schedule this wrapper using the system cron daemon (if on UNIX).